# How to apply condition inside column. If column having array data?

Tags: database, codeigniter

Suppose I have `category` table and having name field.
Inside `name` column I have array data like ["News","Entairntment","Food"].
Here how will I get data which category.name = Food.
Here I can't make where or where_in condition.
Any help.
thanks!!

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you are asking. when you refer to the `name` column, is that a column in your table? If so, you should really look into database normalization.

Comment: if you can use your column as Text it should be enough to use Where name like '%Food%' . It usually helps when the table definitions are posted as well.

Comment: I think you need to follow normalization rule to fix this issue easily reference link [https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/]

Comment: if you still want to use your existing thing then please convert your array in comma-separated with `implode` and save it in `name` column then you can use "%Food%" to fetch the relevant data